# Was my computer poorly designed with problems not only with Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, tty, ham-radio, chirp

Most recent point of confusion: Installed apps that seem to be invisible to the operating system.  An example is one named Chirp.  Ubuntu item at the top of the launcher can't find it.  Apt will list it.  Locate can find a directory by the name - not the executable.  Yet not only can I see the app in the launcher, but it's running in the background.  This invisibility has happened more than once.

Comment: How did you install it? if you used one of the standard package management tools (Software Center, apt-get, or dpkg) then `dpkg -L chirp` should list the locations of all the files, including executables. FYI the `locate` command relies on a database that is only updated periodically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about other programs, but I just installed Chirp from the [Following Page](http://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Running_Under_Linux) and it installed. If you can't find it you can run it from a terminal like so

```
chirpw &
```

For those who might be interested, Chrirp is a program to allow a serial port to program HAM radios.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-hams-updates/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chirp
```